# create a video file from series of png images

Tags: video, avconv, png, mov

I know there a lot of similar questions, but for some reason even after reading them it does not work. I would like to create a video from a series of png-files.

The files are named like

```
img_0000000001_something.png img_0000000002_something.png img_0000000003_something.png
```

If I try

```
avconv -i 'img_%010d_int.png' -r 20 intensity.mkv
```

or

```
avconv -i "img_int%010d*.png" -r 20 -c:v libx264 -crf 20  -pix_fmt yuv420p intensity.mov
```

(where the latter one gives my desired format) i get the following error message:

```
img_%010d_int.png: No such file or directory
```

alhtough I am certainly in the folder, where the png-files are.

Any suggestions? Could it be the `_something`?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "%010d" syntax is only for output files

Instead of

```
avconv -i 'img_%010d_int.png' -r 20 intensity.mkv
```

use

```
avconv -i 'img_*_int.png' -r 20 intensity.mkv
```